# get value from textbox within repeater asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I've been trying to get this working for a couple of hours now but nothing from google could help me fix the problem.

I have a very simple repeater control:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="userDefDiv" Visible="false" runat="server">
                <asp:Repeater ID="userDefRepeater" EnableViewstate="false" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox><br/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:Panel>
```

the userDefDiv panel is inside another panel, which is inside contentPLaceHolder.
the parent panel to userDefDiv does NOT have the "enableviewstate="false"".

So.
Everything on this page happens after a couple of linkbuttons_click. so nothing happens during page_load. And after i click another linkbutton i want to get the data from the different textboxes that is within the repeater.

C# code:

This is the code to create all the repeater items.

```
public void createUserDef()
{
        DataTable userDefData;
        userDefData = ..... (data from Database.)

            userDefDiv.Visible = true;
            userDefRepeater.DataSource = userDefData;
            userDefRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

The code for the linkbutton:

```
protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createUserDef();

    Label2.Visible = true;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in userDefRepeater.Items)
    {
        TextBox box = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");
        string b = box.Text;
        Label2.Text += b + " . ";
    }
}
```

As you see i create the repeater once again during the click. But the only thing i can read in label2. is a a number of " .", on dot for each textbox.
but the text from the textbox is empty..
What am I doing wrong??

thanks for reading!
Mattias

SOLUTION:

1. add EnableVIewState="true" to textbox & repeater.
2. Dont call call dataBind() before you get the values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set EnableViewState to 'true' for linkbuttons to work properly in a repeater

Comment: there is no linkbutton in the repeater. the linkbutton is outside the userDefDiv panel.

Comment: Oh, I see - I was fooled by the click method name. Anyway, the same answer should work. The values of text boxes within a repeater will not be available on a poastback unless EnableViewState=true.

Comment: Is your createUserDef method being called on post back, before your button code executes? If so, it overwites the posted-back values with the original values from the database.

Comment: Thanks man! That was the problem.. Actually, i've read on the internet that you HAVE TO bind the repeater once again. Thats why called the function..