# Creating Comment box With Reply Option using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am tring to Create a **Comment box having reply option** for my Website

Below Is My aspx page

```
 <div>

                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repAnswer">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h6>Answer</h6>

                        <p><%# Eval("Answer") %></p>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsId" Text='<%# Eval("AnsId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                        <a class="link" id='lnkReplyParent<%#Eval("AnsId") %>' href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showReply(<%#Eval("AnsId") %>);return false;">Reply</a>   

                        <a class="link" id="lnkCancle" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeReply(<%#Eval("AnsId") %>);return false;">Cancle</a>  

                          <div id='divReply<%#Eval("AnsId") %>' style="display:none;">  
                             <asp:TextBox ID="textCommentReplyParent" CssClass="input-group" runat="server" Width="300px" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>  
                             <br />  
                             <asp:Button ID="btnReplyParent" runat="server" Text="Reply" OnClick="btnReply_Click" /></div>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </div>
             <div style="margin-top:100px">
                 <h5>Your Answer</h5>
                 <hr />
                <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtAddAnswer" BasePath="Admin/ckeditor/" runat="server">
             </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAnswer" Text="Submit Answer" OnClick="btnAnswer_Click"/>
            </div>
```

i have used Repeater to bind my answer or comment. Inside the repeater i have given two link pne is of reply other is of cancel.when someone click on the reply a new  textbox and button open which is used to give the reply

Below is my cs page

```
 protected void btnReply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem row in repAnswer.Items)
        {
            Label lblNewAnsIdholder = (Label)row.FindControl("lblNewAnsIdholder");
            TextBox txtReplyToAnswer = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtReplyToAnswer");

            OnlineSubjects onlinesub = new OnlineSubjects()
            {
                reply = txtReplyToAnswer.Text.Trim(),
                AnsId = Convert.ToInt32(lblNewAnsIdholder.Text.ToString())
            };
            onlinesub.addAnswer();
        }          
    }
```

i dont know how to use textbox in repeater but after searching it through google i get something like this which i am not sure thats right or wrong.
And the line where i have created my object for my class i am getting error from there
I am tring to pass the value of textbox as a paramter
Plz help me to do this.
Thank You

Comment: [Hope this will help you][1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446226/get-value-from-textbox-within-repeater-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for ur rply..but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try,

`TextBox txtReplyToAnswer = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtReplyToAnswer")).Text;`

Hope this will work.

Comment: What I am seeing in your code is you are referring wrong Textbox id in the repeater.
Ideally, it should be as per your code "textCommentReplyParent" but you are referring "txtReplyToAnswer".